# 500 Internal Server error for all websites on ONLY ONE of two webservers

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, permissions

I have a NFS server setup with 2 web servers (all linux apache2 ). On one of the servers everything works fine. But on the other webserver, all websites return a 500 Internal Server error. The error logs for the sites say `end of script output before headers: index.php`.

From Googling, I am lead to believe this is a permissions issue, but I went through the website files (for one site) on each web server and made sure they are the exact same. Even tried with 777 permissions and the error persists.

Is there a configuration file with incorrect permissions set?

index.php:

```
/** * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it. * * @var bool */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Since the 500 is so general, I would suggest to compare both httpd.conf files and the php.ini files from both servers (assuming that both have the SAME Apache/PHP versions) to see if anything differs.  As to the file permissions (as you may already know), those should be set to 644 and directories to 755. Then ensure to restart Apache if any config changes were made to either files.

Comment: Both those files are the exact same. I have permissions at 775, but I assume that should work since it is looser than 775/644

Comment: Other things that come to mind: is the user/group info for the files and directories the same as the 'working' system? ... Are there any 0-length files?  This can happen after extracting a large archive, followed by an immediate reboot. To avoid this, the sync command is typically run before rebooting.  Are you able to post any code from that index.php file ?

Comment: The user/groups are different, but I didn't manually change these between when the server worked and when it didn't. Unless something automatically changed them, they have been the same. Sites with the same users/groups between the servers do not work on the bad server anyways.

Comment: index.php below

Comment: Does **FILE** have some other definition?  I would have expected that to appear as `__FILE__` (double underscores on both sides) instead.  I guess check if it's the same way on the other system.

Comment: not sure what happened there, it all index.php's have` __FILE__` not FILE

Comment: It looks like the site formatted the double underscores to bold the FILE text, which is why code such as that needs other formatting to avoid those matters.  Anyway, I'm running out of other ideas at the moment. Now knowing wordpress, my help may be limited, as I've never dealt with that environment, but I wouldn't think that it would cause that much trouble. (but I could also be wrong on this assessment).  I dropped the 'server' tag and added 'wordpress', so that this might attract users more familiar with wordpress configuration(s).

Comment: Please explain how NFS comes into play and how it's configured. if both web servers access the website files from this NFS server, I'd check the mounting permissions, and also try with local files to rule out any server Apache/PHP  configuration issue